# Two conductors in free space

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy-conservation, conductors

> In free space there are two masses:
>
> - Metallic sphere of mass $M$, radius $R$ and total charge equal to 0. It has also a resistivity $\rho$.
> - Metallic sphere of mass $m$, radius $r$ and charge $q$.
>
> The distance between the masses is $d$. We can assume $r \ll R \ll d$ and $m \ll M$. The masses start accelerating until they collide anelasticaly. Find the energy that has become heat.

My question is: Why do I need $\rho$ to solve this problem?

My solution is basically finding the difference between the initial potential energy and the final, but i haven't used the resistivity.

Comment: Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: You might want to ask about this [in the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) as we're generally happy to discuss homework questions there.